# IE9 Doesn't reflect changes to page by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

I'm using jQuery to alter page elements and the code appears to be running (successfully) but the page doesn't actually update immediately. Everything's stable in Chrome, but IE9 is being strange.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('change', '.Hours', function () {
        var hoursElement = this;
        this.value = Math.ceil(this.value * 4) / 4;
        $.post("/Log/UpdateWorkItemHours", { 
        //valid arguments
        }, function (hours) { 
            hoursElement.value = hours;
            updateSum(); 
        });
    });
});

function updateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.Hours').each(function () {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').text("Total Hours: " + sum);
    alert(sum);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="numeric Hours" value="4"   />
<input type="text" class="numeric Hours" value="4"   />
<input type="text" class="numeric Hours" value="21"   />

<span class="numeric" id="sum">Total Hours: 0</span>
```

My alert occurs AFTER (in the code) the contents of #sum should be changed, and it displays the right number, however, the page doesn't update until I click randomly around the page or change focus using tab a couple times. Also, the alert is just for debugging; this was happening before I added it in there.

Order of the code:
1. Figure out the sum
2. Update the page
3. Make an alert popup

Order of execution:
1. Figure out the sum
2. Make an alert popup
3. Wait until the user clicks on stuff randomly
4. Update the page

Any ideas?

EDIT: added HTML and the event that calls the function.

Comment: When does this function get called? What's the HTML of the page that it interacts with?

Comment: Does it work without the alert? IE doesn't really like to do alerts

Comment: @thantos From the question: "Also, the alert is just for debugging; this was happening before I added it in there."

Comment: Since when does IE "not like to do alerts"?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, I updated this to include the html and where the function is called.

Comment: @JustinToman Your jQuery code references elements with the class `Hours` on them - where are they in the HTML you provided?

Comment: Have you tried rapid-fire(tm) ctrl-r? ie could be caching old version of your script. (ie especially loves doing that)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, sorry, I added it now.

Comment: Speaking of caching, I'm not sure how IE caching the response from a previous AJAX call would affect things. Try setting the `cache` property to `false` using `$.ajaxSetup({cache : false});` and see if it helps?

Comment: I put together a basic [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dUB3/) using the HTML and jQuery code you provided, but everything seems to work as I'd expect in IE9.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, I just tried the link you gave me in IE9 and I'm having the same problem. So could this be something wrong with my installation/setup? The thing is, this is something that my entire company uses, and everyone (to my knowledge) reports the same bugs. At the moment we're just telling people not to use IE9. Could something be wrong with our domain? I'm admittedly new to this stuff, but it seems weird that it's not broken for you.

Comment: Bit of a random thought, but: I've been testing this by changing the value in one of the text boxes, then clicking out of the element - and seeing the same (correct) functionality in all three browsers (IE, Firefox and Chrome). However, had a random thought, and tried hitting return (rather than clicking out of the element), and it stops working in IE, but continues to work in Firefox and Chrome. Does that sound like what you're doing?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to lie in timing of the callback function. If you take that piece out, everything works as expected in IE:

```
$('body').on('change', '.Hours', function () {
    this.value = Math.ceil(this.value * 4) / 4;
    updateSum();
});
```

I realize the post is likely creating the input to be added together, just trying to help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I tried to edit out the irrelevant parts of the code to make it easier to understand, but yes you are correct. If a user tries to enter an invalid amount to the hours text box, the controller will send back a value that the javascript uses to replace the bad value. updateSum has to happen after the bad value is replaced, so it has to happen after the controller has responded, which is in the callback function.

Comment: @JustinToman May as well post the code that does the replacement as well. While it seems unlikely it will be the cause of the problem, I can't see/think of anything wrong with the code you've posted so far.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/sepsJ/ in IE9. It's not quite as reproducible as when I do it with all the extra stuff on the page, but this is a more complete picture of the way it all works. Click directly to the right of the input field after you change something. That should prevent the change event from being called. Tabbing around seems to trigger it, though.

Comment: How could it be the callback timing? It shows the alert that happens after the sum should be updated. That means the function ran, and it got past the part where the sum should be updated. The part I'm most confused about is this: How is it possible that the alert gets called but the page doesn't change?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one element with an ID of **sum**?  Chrome may be choosing the first one while IE is choosing a different one (or none at all).

I'd have to dig up my web security book but I remember reading they handle that situation differently.

**Edit:**

Just tested [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeM8H/1/) in Chrome and IE7-9 with the code you've provided (minus the AJAX call of course) and it works fine.

So either your AJAX call is failing in IE (unlikely) or you have syntax errors that I can't see.

Comment: Nope, just copied the page rendered by IE into notepad and searched for the word "sum" and it only came up once.

Comment: Need to see the raw HTML.  At least the HTML containing your elements with `.Hours` classes

Answer (score 0):

try changing line

```
this.value = Math.ceil(this.value * 4) / 4;
```

to

```
$(this).val(Math.ceil($(this).val() * 4) / 4;)
```

Comment: Unnecessary function calls to fix a non-existent problem with a line of code that seems unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Yes, this is completely redundant syntax and is not at all related to the problem.